# Qt, click signal in client area

Tags: c++, qt, click, signals, paint

I want to create a program like MS Paint using the Qt Framework and I was wondering how to connect the "clicked" signal, that is activated every time the user click the program window in the client area. Something like WM_LBUTTONDOWN in Win32 API.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `clicked()` signal in QWidget.

You have to subclass QWidget and reimplement `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);` which will give you the coordinates (in the widget's coordinate system) via `event->pos();` or `event->x();` and `event->y();` after including the header: `#include <QMouseEvent>`.

You might be interested in the [Scribble Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-scribble.html).